# Rsync exclude-from through ssh

Tags: ssh, rsync

I want to rsync content from a remote host to my laptop through ssh.
There are files I want to exclude, and in the remote host, there is a file called ".rsyncexclude" that specifies what I want to exclude.

So I run the following command:

```
rsync -av --progress --delete --exclude-from='username@example.com:remote/path/to/folder/to/sync/.rsyncignore' --delete-excluded username@example.com:remote/path/to/folder/to/sync/ local/path/to/folder/to/sync/
```

But I get the following error:

```
rsync: failed to open exclude file username@example.com:remote/path/to/folder/to/sync/.rsyncignore: No such file or directory (2)
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The `--exclude-from` option specifies a file that the local rsync process should read to add to the exclude list. It does not support the notation you used to read the file from the remote host; it interprets the filename as a path to a local file, which is why you are getting the error `failed to open exclude file username@example.com:remote/path/to/folder/to/sync/.rsyncignore` as it's trying to open exactly that file.

I don't think that there is a way to do what you want, short of first transferring the `.rsyncignore` file to the local host and then referencing that file via the `--exclude-from` option.

You may be helped by using the `-F` option, that specifies a per-directory file `.rsync-filter` that gets read on the source side.